# discord.js EvaluatedPermissions other solution

Tags: node.js, express, eval, discord.js

uptill now when i was in v11.x.x i was using

my dashboard.js looks like this

```
    const perms = Discord.EvaluatedPermissions;
    renderTemplate(res, req, "dashboard.ejs", {perms});
```

but now perms is undefined when i updated bot to discord.js v12 
and they said `evaluatedPermissions` has been removed entirely, see the `Permissions` page

what can i do to replace  `Discord.EvaluatedPermissions` to get perms

so i can use it in my dashboard.ejs file

```
  user.guilds.forEach(guild => { 
    const permsOnGuild = new perms(guild.permissions);
    if(!permsOnGuild.has("MANAGE_GUILD")) return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
const perms = Discord.EvaluatedPermissions
```

to

```
const perms = Discord.Permissions
```

since the permissions are send in bits ie `permissions: 104193601,` if i `console.log`

```
console.log(user.guilds)
   user.guilds.forEach(guild => { 

}
```

idk but adding cache to it made forEach `undefined`